# Cannot run in production mode

Tags: production-environment, donejs

I have a donejs application and its running ok in development mode `donejs develop`, but when I run it in production mode:

1. `donejs build`
2. `donejs deploy` (to firebase)
3. `NODE_ENV=production donejs start`

it will not start and show an error (see CODE A)

This file: `file:my-app/dist/bundles/my-app/index.js:704` corresponds to JQuery 3.x and its not a dependency of the project itself but a dependency of can-connect-feathers (https://github.com/canjs/can-connect-feathers). In fact in `index.js` there is also included JQuery 2.x what makes me think there might be some sort of incompatibility among them.

I already tried changing the project's dependency to JQuery 3.x but didn't help. Actually it will make even `donejs develop` fail (see CODE B).

I also tried the following:
  `cd my-app/node_modules/steal`
  `npm install`
but didn't help, another error appears and finally tried `cd my-app/node_modules/can && npm install` but that end up in multiple errors.

I'm using:

- donejs@0.9.2
- node@4.6.2
- npm@2.15.11
- can-connect-feathers@1.2.1

#### CODE A

`NODE_ENV=production donejs start`

`my-app@0.0.0 start my-app
    done-serve --proxy http://localhost:3030 --port 8080
    done-serve starting on http://localhost:8080
    Potentially unhandled rejection [5] TypeError: Error loading "package.json!npm" at file:my-app/package.json
    Error loading "bundles/my-app/index" at file:my-app/dist/bundles/my-app/index.js
    Error evaluating file:my-app/dist/bundles/my-app/index.js
    Cannot read property 'createElement' of undefined
        at i (file:my-app/dist/bundles/my-app/index.js:704:20)
        at file:my-app/dist/bundles/my-app/index.js:1039:2881
        at file:my-app/dist/bundles/my-app/index.js:1039:3580
        at file:my-app/dist/bundles/my-app/index.js:268:21
        at file:my-app/dist/bundles/my-app/index.js:268:27
        at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:54:17)
        at doEval (my-app/node_modules/steal/node_modules/steal-systemjs/dist/system.src.js:2059:10)
        at __eval (my-app/node_modules/steal/node_modules/steal-systemjs/dist/system.src.js:1976:7)
        at Loader.exec [as __exec] (my-app/node_modules/steal/node_modules/steal-systemjs/dist/system.src.js:339:5)
        at Loader.loader.instantiate (my-app/node_modules/steal/node_modules/steal-systemjs/dist/system.src.js:1517:16)`

#### CODE B

`donejs develop`

`my-app@0.0.0 develop my-app
    done-serve --develop --proxy http://localhost:3030 --port 8080
    done-serve starting on http://localhost:8080
    Potentially unhandled rejection [8] Error: Error loading "my-app@0.0.0#index.stache!done-autorender@0.8.0#autorender" at <unknown>
    Error loading "can@2.3.27#util/jquery/jquery" at file:my-app/node_modules/can/util/jquery/jquery.js
    Error loading "can@2.3.27#util/jquery/jquery" from "done-autorender@0.8.0#autorender" at file:my-app/node_modules/done-autorender/src/autorender.js
    Did not find ./node_modules/can/node_modules/jquery/package.json
        at FetchTask.utils.extend.next (file:my-app/node_modules/steal/ext/npm-crawl.js:532:11)
        at file:my-app/node_modules/steal/ext/npm-crawl.js:556:33
        at tryCatchReject (my-app/node_modules/steal/node_modules/steal-systemjs/node_modules/steal-es6-module-loader/dist/es6-module-loader.src.js:1183:30)
        at runContinuation1 (my-app/node_modules/steal/node_modules/steal-systemjs/node_modules/steal-es6-module-loader/dist/es6-module-loader.src.js:1142:4)
        at Fulfilled.when (my-app/node_modules/steal/node_modules/steal-systemjs/node_modules/steal-es6-module-loader/dist/es6-module-loader.src.js:930:4)
        at Pending.run (my-app/node_modules/steal/node_modules/steal-systemjs/node_modules/steal-es6-module-loader/dist/es6-module-loader.src.js:821:13)
        at Scheduler._drain (my-app/node_modules/steal/node_modules/steal-systemjs/node_modules/steal-es6-module-loader/dist/es6-module-loader.src.js:97:19)
        at Scheduler.drain (my-app/node_modules/steal/node_modules/steal-systemjs/node_modules/steal-es6-module-loader/dist/es6-module-loader.src.js:62:9)
        at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:436:9)
        at process._tickCallback (node.js:365:13)
    Potentially unhandled rejection [16] Error: Error loading "can@2.3.27#util/jquery/jquery" at file:my-app/node_modules/can/util/jquery/jquery.js
    Error loading "can@2.3.27#util/jquery/jquery" from "my-app@0.0.0#index.stache!done-autorender@0.8.0#autorender" at file:my-app/src/index.stache
    Did not find ./node_modules/can/node_modules/jquery/package.json
        at FetchTask.utils.extend.next (file:my-app/node_modules/steal/ext/npm-crawl.js:532:11)
        at file:my-app/node_modules/steal/ext/npm-crawl.js:556:33
        at tryCatchReject (my-app/node_modules/steal/node_modules/steal-systemjs/node_modules/steal-es6-module-loader/dist/es6-module-loader.src.js:1183:30)
        at runContinuation1 (my-app/node_modules/steal/node_modules/steal-systemjs/node_modules/steal-es6-module-loader/dist/es6-module-loader.src.js:1142:4)
        at Fulfilled.when (my-app/node_modules/steal/node_modules/steal-systemjs/node_modules/steal-es6-module-loader/dist/es6-module-loader.src.js:930:4)
        at Pending.run (my-app/node_modules/steal/node_modules/steal-systemjs/node_modules/steal-es6-module-loader/dist/es6-module-loader.src.js:821:13)
        at Scheduler._drain (my-app/node_modules/steal/node_modules/steal-systemjs/node_modules/steal-es6-module-loader/dist/es6-module-loader.src.js:97:19)
        at Scheduler.drain (my-app/node_modules/steal/node_modules/steal-systemjs/node_modules/steal-es6-module-loader/dist/es6-module-loader.src.js:62:9)
        at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:436:9)
        at process._tickCallback (node.js:365:13)`

Comment: I"m not sure why it's failing, but your point of there being two jQuery versions brings up a good point about how I built can-connect-feathers.  I should pull out jQuery and make it something that you pass in.  It won't be a problem at all once the 2.0 prerelease is finished, because it uses the actual feathers-client.  Can you go into your node_modules/can-connect-feathers folder and npm install a 2.x version of jQuery and try again?  I'll make an issue to remove jQuery from the repo in GitHub.

Comment: I just published a version that allows you to pass a specific version of jQuery: `npm install can-connect-feathers@2.0.0 --save`.  Please see if that fixes it for you.  The prerelease is now 3.0.0-pre.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the double jQuery installation is the issue, it should be resolved by version 2.0.0, which is exactly the same as the 1.0 version, but requires that you pass in a jQuery package as the `jquery` option.  So, in addition to whatever else you had in your can-connect-feathers config, you'll need to provide the `jquery` option:

```js
import $ from 'jquery'
import Feathers from 'can-connect-feathers';

new Feathers({
  jquery: $
});
```